# Period between dates using Java/Joda

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I have 2 joda dates as follows:

```
org.joda.time.DateTime a;
org.joda.time.DateTime b;
```

I want the difference between the 2 dates in terms of Years, months and days (eg. 0 years, 2 months, 5 days). 
I can use the `org.joda.time.Days.daysBetween(a, b)` or `monthsBetween(a, b)` or `yearsBetween(a, b)` to get the whole values of each respectively.
Since a month does have number of fixed number of days, how can I calculate this?

Eg. If I get `monthsbetween = 2` and `daysbetween = 65`, how can I write this as `"2 months and x days"`

Is there any other way to get this?

Comment: Did you take a look at something like `Period( a.getMillis(), b.getMillis(), PeriodType.yearMonthDay() )`?

Comment: Thanks! In combination with `org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter`, your suggestion of using a `Period` works well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
ca.setTime(a);
Calendar cb = Calendar.getInstance();
cb.setTime(b);
System.out.printf("%d months and %d days"
    , ca.get(Calendar.MONTH) - cb.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    , ca.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - cb.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @n0741337's suggested way does exactly what I want :).

Answer (score 0):

Im not too familiar with Joda, but it looks like your best option is to divide the days left by 30.5, and then round it up back to a whole integer. Like so:

```
double daysDivided = daysbetween / 30.5;
int daysbetweenFixed = (int) daysDivided;

System.out.printf("%d months and %d days", monthsbetween, daysbetweenFixed);
//optional output ^
```

I'm sure you would know i chose 30.5 because it seems like the a good average month length, excluding February. Because there is no set length of a month this is the best we can do with only these integers.

Comment: I thought of doing this, but for the month of February this would give me a answer which is way off :)